ROS: Further understanding the diffrence of MultiThreadedSpinner and AsyncSpinner
I have several years of experience with robot software development using ROS, especially ROS Noetic. I want to clarify my understanding about ros::MultiThreadedSpinner and ros::AsyncSpinner.
All I know is that Multi Threaded Spinner is Blocking and Async is not? am I correct? let's say I have 16 cpu Threads, and I have 16 subscribers, and I'm using ros rate loop, when I'm using multi threaded spinner, it has possibilities that the rate loop wont run, but when using the async spinner, the callbacks would run Asynchronously, and the loop would run as it has nothing to do with the threads.
Am I correct with my understanding? help me clarify my statements.
